# Engaging rampart security module, XML/code declaration

Tags: java, apache-axis, rampart

What is the best/correct way for engaging the rampart security module.

> module ref="rampart"

in axis2.xml file or

> ServiceClient sc = stub._getServiceClient();
>
> sc.engageModule("rampart");

will be pleased if someone can explain what is achieved by each of these
declarations.